# iOS - center.y doesn't move in view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` with a separated `UIView` inside it. This view has some textfields. If the user taps on one of the fields, the view will automatically fit his `center.y`. In the end the textfield which the user tapped will be in the middle of the screen. But in my case the view doesn't move. In the simulator it worked great, but on a real phone nothing happens. Only the output `center.y` position changes. I fixed the `UIView` with constraints.

Here is the code for the tap action.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 0
    textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
    textField.text = ""
    print("Began")
    let textFieldCoInView = textField.center
    let coInSelf = self.dataView.convert(textFieldCoInView, to: self.view)
    print(coInSelf)
    print(self.view.center.y)
    if(coInSelf.y > self.view.center.y) {
        dataViewOriginY = dataView.center.y
        print("Works")
        self.dataView.center.y = self.dataView.center.y - (coInSelf.y - self.view.center.y)
        print(self.dataView.center.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: what constraint you had provided to view?

Answer (score 0):

> "I fixed the UIView with constraints."

If the view you're trying to move has constraints on it, autolayout is probably fighting you. to test that theory try turning off constraints for the view you're moving.

If that's it, you'll probably need to do something like make outlets to the constraints and change the values in your code (or not use constraints).

In any case, I think you'll find that autolayout is fighting you and keeping the view where its constraints say it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the constraint you have set for the `UIView` . and also check the console for errors. Constraints can stop the code to change view. Maybe turn off the constraint and check if the code works.